# Resizing window Jquery

Tags: jquery

When I scroll down into my website, I want my header to reduce its height. So I wrote this code :

```
function resizeHeader() {
    if ($(window).width() > 1200) {
        if ($('body').hasClass('scrolled')) {
            $('#masthead .top-header').css('height', '50px');
        } else {
            //Initial height
            $('#masthead .top-header').css('height', 'auto');
        }
    } else if ($(window).width() > 768 && $(window).width() < 989) {
        if ($('body').hasClass('scrolled')) {
            $('#masthead .top-header').css('height', '35px');
        } else {
            $('#masthead .top-header').css('height', 'auto');
        }
    }
}

/** Fix header scroll **/
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {
        $('body').addClass('scrolled');
        resizeHeader();
    } else {
        $('body').removeClass('scrolled');
        resizeHeader();
    }
});
```

So this code works, when I refresh my page at the wanted size, the script is working.

However, when i refresh and then I resize my window, then my header has not the height I set for this size

What I want is when I resize my window, the function is running and do action. it's always working when I refresh my page and not when I resize it.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: As suggested by Rory, you would have better to use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to trigger a `scroll` event on load of the page so that your code runs. Try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    // your code here...
}).trigger('scroll'); // < trigger on load
```

Also note that it would be much more appropriate to put the logic of your `resizeHeader()` function in to a responsive CSS stylesheet using media queries, something like this:

```
#masthead .top-header {
    height: auto;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .scrolled #masthead .top-header {
    height: 50px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 989px) {
  .scrolled #masthead .top-header {
    height: 35px;
  }
}
```

```js
var scrollTimer;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    clearTimeout(scrollTimer);
    scrollTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        $('body').toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > 1);
    }, 250);
}).trigger('scroll');
```

Comment: I think OP wants to bind resize event indeed: `What I want is when I resize my window, the function is running and do action`

Comment: Yeah I forgot that I can achieve that with responsive media queries, I'm trying this solution

Comment: Yes It works with media queries. Thanks a lot for the reminder !